# Seeding fails: "field can't be blank" but I'm seeding with a value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, seeding

I have a required field for the `Article` table:

```
t.string  :article_type, null: false
```

And in the model:

```
validates :article_type,  presence: true
enum article_type:        [ :type1, :type2, :type3, :type4, :type5 ]
```

In my seeds I have:

```
books = Book.all
books.each do |book|
  title = Faker::Lorem.sentence(3)
  article_type = ["type1", "type2", "type3", "type4", "type5"].sample
  book.articles.create!( title: title,
                         article_type: article_type )
end
```

**Problem:** The `create` line produces the error: `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Article type can't be blank`. What could be causing this? (I can confirm that the `.sample` line works and picks one of the five types)

**Update:** If I change `article_type` from string to integer, it works. What should I do? Because it isn't really an integer, is it...?

Comment: try this: `article_type = -> { ["type1", "type2", "type3", "type4", "type5"].sample }.call`

Comment: Thanks, the `create` line than fails with the error: ``block in <top (required)>'`

Comment: hm, do not see any reason for that to happen

Comment: I've extended the original post with the full method (`each` loop added), which perhaps explains the error?

Comment: What about this? `article_type = -> { ["type1", "type2", "type3", "type4", "type5"].sample }.call
title = -> { Faker::Lorem.sentence(3) }.call
books.each { |book| book.articles.create!(title: title,article_type: article_type) }`

Comment: can you add the whole stack trace?

Comment: Added the stack trace to the OP. I also found out it all does work if I change `article_type` to an integer. Does that make sense?

Comment: Of course, how did I not notice it was an enum type. It should be integer

Comment: Would replacing the `enum` line with `validates_inclusion_of :article_type, :in => ["type1", "type2", "type3", "type4", "type5"]` be proper code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails `enum` expects corresponding db column to be integer, but yours is a string.

So either change to integer or substitute enum with value validation.

Comment: Would replacing the `enum` line with `validates_inclusion_of :article_type, :in => ["type1", "type2", "type3", "type4", "type5"]` be proper code?

Comment: @Marty yes. Also enum creates scopes for each value and methods like `type1?`

Answer (score 0):

Try and isolate the error. See if this seeds without any issues maybe then keep segmenting?

```
article_type = "type1"
book.articles.create!( title: title,
                         article_type: article_type )
```